# Which opensource web framework to choose for a data portal?

Tags: web, frameworks, open-source

My organization needs to develop a data portal similar to this one: http://dataportal.afdb.org/ however giving the numerous web frameworks and languages available I been asked to query for suitable one.

We would like to use a web framework that is clean, open source, scalable and flexible but most importantly that we could develop our portal very fast.

Which web framework would you recommend and why?

Thanks a lot.

Carlos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well the link you provided http://dataportal.afdb.org/default.aspx seems to be running the .Net language (hence the .aspx extension). This could also include C# in the back end which would be a good choice for a data heavy application.

From digging around in the source I see that they are also using WebResource.axd which likely is referring to the use of an Ajax library for the .Net code found at http://www.asp.net/ajax.

I also see JQuery in there but a JavaScript framework is almost a requirement for any web app.

I would start looking at these resources and see what you need for your project. Also remember if you have to run your app on existing servers that there are Microsoft vs Linux languages. .Net, C# and the ajax.net library all live in the Microsoft world so they wouldn't work on a Linux server natively.

As a side note Im a HUGE promoter of [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) for highly interactive and or data heavy applications so if your building from the ground up it would be an extremely useful framework to incorporate.

Comment: Mind posting the reason why this was voted down?